# VBA ADODB foreach rows and columns

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, adodb

How can I `foreach` the returned rows from `ADODB.Resultset`? And is it possible to get values by column name (for example if I want to get value from column "name" at row 3 to cell A1)?

Here is my current code without any loops:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection

oConn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};Server=****;Database=****;Uid=****;Pwd=****;"

Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset

oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM report_access", oConn, adOpenStatic

With oRS
    Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset oRS
End With
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this for iteration 

  while not (ors.EOF Or ors.BOF)

    for each x in ors.Fields
       'Assign cell content

    next
  ors.MoveNext

wend
```

Comment: Please don't post just code, explain it, so the OP can learn from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can move the queried data to an array using the 'GetRows' and get the values from the array as you wish

For example

```
arr = oRS.GetRows

i = 0
If Not (oRS.EOF And oRS.BOF) Then
oRS.MoveFirst
    Do Until oRS.EOF = True
        MsgBox arr(0, i)
        i = i + 1
        oRS.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If
```

This will Alert the first column values

Note : Here arr(3,2) means 3rd column and 2nd row

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can move to row 3 with 3 `oRS.MoveNext`

```
while not oRS.EOF And oRS.AbsolutePosition < 2
    oRS.MoveNext
wend
[A1] = oRS.Fields("name")
```

or you can find the index of the "name" field and use `oRS.GetRows`

```
Dim nameIndex As Integer

For nameIndex = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1
    If oRS.Fields(nameIndex).Name = "name" Then Exit For
Next 

arr = oRS.GetRows

[a1] = arr(2, nameIndex)
```

**Update**

You can probably use `oRS.Move`

```
oRS.Move 2
[A1] = oRS.Fields("name")
```